# not playing audio from buffer stored in the database

Tags: blob, html5-audio, audio-streaming, webm, opus

I've spent 2 days with this thing and couldn't find a solution but seems like im getting closer. The goal is to record audio in the browser and store in the the database and get it whenever i need it.

I encoded the audio to base64 and sent it to the server stored as binary in the mongodb, created a get route in which i find the audio by id  and send the buffer via res.send() along with the content type set to audio/webm (default mime type)

but the thing is I'm getting this blank video, seems like it's not knowing how to decode it or something. There might be something wrong with the content type.

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: false })
    .then((mediaRecorderObj) => {
        let mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaRecorderObj, { mimType: 'audio/webm;base64' })
        const m = mediaRecorder;
        let chunk = []
        startBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            mediaRecorder.start()
            console.log('started recording..');
        })
        endBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            mediaRecorder.stop()
            console.log('just stopped recording');
        })
        //-----When Data Is Available
        mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (e) => {
            chunk.push(e.data);
        }

        //--------When finished adding it to chunk
        mediaRecorder.onstop = () => {
            const blob = new Blob(chunk, { 'type': 'audio/webm' })
            chunk = []
            const reader = new FileReader()
            reader.readAsDataURL(blob)
            reader.onloadend = async () => {
                const buffer = reader.result
                const bodyObj = {
                    voice: buffer
                }
                await fetch('http://localhost:3000/upload-spoken-bio', {
                    method: 'post',
                    body: JSON.stringify(bodyObj),
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
                })
            }
        }
    })
```

and this is the server side

```
//----------Upload
spokenBio.post('/upload-spoken-bio', async (req, res) => {
    const buffer = req.body
    try {
        const newBuffer = new SpokenCon(buffer)
        await newBuffer.save()
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    }
})

//----------Retrieve
spokenBio.get('/get-spoken-bio/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id
    try {
        const field = await SpokenCon.findById(id)
        const binary = field.voice
        res.set({ 'Content-Type': 'audio/webm' })
        res.send(binary)
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    }
})
```

Comment: Why are you encoding as base64?  And not only that, but then putting that data in JSON.  You're adding a massive amount of overhead.  Additionally, it doesn't seem to me that you're storing binary after all, since `req.body` is JSON, not binary data.